# Obtain top 20 most appear element and store into a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp

Below is the following code that I have to retrieve the top 20 most appear elements

```
countStemWords = Counter(ListofStemWords)
countStemWords.most_common(20)
```

I understand that Counter is a subclass of Dict where the keys are the word that appears and the values are the number of times the word appear. What I'm trying to do is to retrieve just the keys without the values for top 20 most appear words and store them into a list. For example,

```
('code', 4193), ('gt', 1522), ('python', 1293)...
```

to

```
(code), (gt), (python)...
```

and store the result(without the brackets and comma) to a list such that

```
list[0] = code, list[1] = gt list[2] = python
```

Comment: `top20 = [token for token, count in countStemWords.most_common(20)]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a list comprehension:

```
top_twenty = [item[0] for item in countStemWords.most_common(20)]
```

This will give you exactly the list you specified.